# OpenCV warpPerspective rotation inconsistency

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

After finding the largest contour (which is a coupon in this case), applying warpPerspective results in inconsistent warping, it rotates some images towards left upon warping but works pretty well for some input frames.

**INPUT IMAGE WHICH YIELDS PERFECT WARPING**

[image: INPUT PERFECT WARPING]

**OUTPUT PERFECT WARPING**

[image: OUTPUT PERFECT WARPING]

**INPUT IMAGE WHICH YIELDS MESSED-UP WARPING**

[image: INPUT MESSED-UP WARPING]

**OUTPUT MESSED-UP WARPING**
[image]

```
    private Mat processMatToFindLargestContourAndApplyWarp(Mat srcMat) {
    Mat processedMat = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(srcMat, processedMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(processedMat, processedMat, new Size(5, 5), 5);
    Imgproc.threshold(processedMat, processedMat, 127, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();

    Imgproc.findContours(processedMat, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    double maxVal = 0;
    int maxValIdx = 0;
    for (int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++) {
        double contourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(contourIdx));
        if (maxVal < contourArea) {
            maxVal = contourArea;
            maxValIdx = contourIdx;
        }
    }

    if (!contours.isEmpty()) {
        Imgproc.drawContours(processedMat, contours, maxValIdx, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);
        return warp(srcMat, contours.get(maxValIdx));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error: Token contour not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return srcMat;
}

public Mat warp(Mat inputMat, MatOfPoint selectedContour) {
    Mat outputMat;
    try {
    MatOfPoint2f new_mat = new MatOfPoint2f(selectedContour.toArray());
    MatOfPoint2f approxCurve_temp = new MatOfPoint2f();
    int contourSize = (int) selectedContour.total();
    Imgproc.approxPolyDP(new_mat, approxCurve_temp, contourSize * 0.05, true);

    double[] temp_double;
    temp_double = approxCurve_temp.get(0,0);
    Point p1 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);
    temp_double = approxCurve_temp.get(1,0);
    Point p3 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);
    temp_double = approxCurve_temp.get(2,0);
    Point p4 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);
    temp_double = approxCurve_temp.get(3,0);
    Point p2 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);
    List<Point> source = new ArrayList<Point>();

    source.add(p1);
    source.add(p2);
    source.add(p3);
    source.add(p4);

    Log.e("inPoints", "" + source);
    Mat startM = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(source);

    int resultWidth = 846;
    int resultHeight = 2048;

    outputMat = new Mat(resultWidth, resultHeight, CvType.CV_8UC4);

        Point ocvPOut1 = new Point(0, 0);
        Point ocvPOut2 = new Point(resultWidth, 0);
        Point ocvPOut3 = new Point(0, resultHeight);
        Point ocvPOut4 = new Point(resultWidth, resultHeight);
    List<Point> dest = new ArrayList<Point>();
    dest.add(ocvPOut1);
    dest.add(ocvPOut2);
    dest.add(ocvPOut3);
    dest.add(ocvPOut4);
    Mat endM = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(dest);

    Mat perspectiveTransform = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(startM, endM);
    Imgproc.warpPerspective(inputMat, outputMat, perspectiveTransform, new Size(resultWidth, resultHeight));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
    return outputMat;
}
```

I have tried switching the edge points, but then it works for the 2nd Image and not for the first one. Do I have to place a check and arrange the points in order, if so, can anyone guide me how, or is there a better approach for handling this issue?

In my log results, the input source points gathered by Imgproc.approxPolyDP are inconsistent in arrangement for different images having the coupon even at a slight angle.

Comment: "Do I have to place a check and arrange the points in order?" yes. You need to come up with a signature which tells you the orientation of the token. IMO this might be handled best by the lion's head logo in the top left---then you know how to orient. If you consider the vector pointing to each subsequent corner from the top left, the angle is always increasing (keeping in mind *y* increases as you go down the image). For the perfect heads on-case the angle is 0, then ~75 degrees, then 90 degrees. But even for the second case, it's like -15, 60, then 80. Always increasing in order.

Comment: Another possible signature may be the mostly-white right border strip.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Thanks for you reply, but do I really have to look for "the lion's head logo in the top" to check for the orientation, as my app will only be used for this coupon and will always be captured having the head side at the top, just need it to adjust the slight change in angle of capturing, is there any other way which is more robust, like ordering the corners clockwise and ignoring the skew of the contour. The resultant image is sometimes flipped upside down as well. And the contour is sometimes missing a chunk from a side as well, can you look at the threshold of the image tha

Comment: If you know that the coupon will never be upside down, or will never be fully sideways, then no---you won't have to do that. Searching for the lions head or some other signature is the most robust IMO since it will work for upside-down coupons, *but* you can get by with a few methods. You can get the `minAreaRect()` (rotated rectangle) that fits around your contours, and reorder your points based on the aspect ratio (just check the h/w or w/h). Or maybe you can just call the nearest of the four points to (0, 0) the top-left and orient from there.

Comment: Honestly I think feature-matching would probably yield better results with a good head-on picture of the ticket as the template, and would solve orientation issues at the same time. See [here](http://dummyscodes.blogspot.com/2015/12/using-siftsurf-for-object-recognition.html) for e.g. You can just warp the image into the coordinates of the template and you should be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed a quick workaround of the situation, I'm sure there will be a better way of achieving this but it works for now, the fix is to manually order the contour points to clock-wise (i.e. TopLeft, TopRight, BottomRight, BottomLeft) every time, regardless of the input points arrangement.

Here is the code if someone is ever stuck at my situation

```
    private Point[] orderCorners(Point[] cornersUnordered) {
    Point[] cornerPoints = new Point[4];
    Point p1, p2, p3, p4;
    Point topLeft = null, topRight = null, botRight = null, botLeft = null;
    List<Point> corners = new ArrayList<Point>();
    for (int i=0; i < cornersUnordered.length; ++i)
        corners.add(cornersUnordered[i]);

    /* Top set of points */
    // find p1
    p1 = corners.get(0);
    for (Point point : corners) {
        if (point.y < p1.y) {
            p1 = point;
        }
    }
    corners.remove(p1);

    // find p2
    p2 = corners.get(0);
    for (Point point : corners) {
        if (distance(p1, point) < distance(p1, p2)) {
            p2 = point;
        }
    }
    corners.remove(p2);

    /* Identify top left and top right */
    /*
     * Note that the logic is safe if the points have equal x values. Safe
     * in the sense that different points will get assigned to topLeft and
     * topRight
     */
    topLeft = p1.x < p2.x ? p1 : p2;
    topRight = p2.x > p1.x ? p2 : p1;

    /* Bottom set of points */
    // corners only contains 2 points, the bottom ones
    p3 = corners.get(0);
    p4 = corners.get(1);
    botRight = p3.x > p4.x ? p3 : p4;
    botLeft = p4.x < p3.x ? p4 : p3;

    cornerPoints[0] = topLeft;
    cornerPoints[1] = topRight;
    cornerPoints[2] = botRight;
    cornerPoints[3] = botLeft;

    return cornerPoints;
}

private double distance(Point p1, Point p2) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((p2.x - p1.x), 2) + Math.pow((p2.y - p1.y), 2));
}
```

And here is the destinationPoints arrangement for the fix above:

```
        Point ocvPOut1 = new Point(0, 0);
        Point ocvPOut2 = new Point(resultWidth, 0);
        Point ocvPOut3 = new Point(resultWidth, resultHeight);
        Point ocvPOut4 = new Point(0, resultHeight);
```

Special thanks to  @Alexander Reynolds